# Batch File - FOR LOOP

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Let me set the stage of my issue. I have a folder (`FOLDER_ABC`). Within that folder, there is a folder for my application, including a unique and always changing version number (`application-v1.3.4`). Within that folder, there is the application (`application-v1.3.4.exe`) - which will also change periodically.

```
C:\FOLDER_ABC\application-v1.3.4\application-v1.3.4.exe
```

In this section below I create a directory listing of the `FOLDER_ABC` for any folders starting with application* and store that folder name into a file called `directory.txt`. I then create a perameter and store that directory into it. I'm doing it this way, versus applying the direct full path to the directory or file, since the versions will change and I don't want to hard code the batch script.

```
cd C:\FOLDER_ABC\
dir  application* /b /ad>"C:\FOLDER_ABC\directory.txt"
set /p verdir= <C:\FOLDER_ABC\directory.txt
```

Here is my issue. In the section below, I'm trying to get my batch script to run the `application*.exe` file, and continue on with my batch file. It currently runs my application, but it hangs and doesn't continue the rest of my batch script. I'm really new to all this coding so I appreciate the help. I assume it could be something related to me not closing the FOR loop properly? How can I get it to continue on to :FINISH?

```
cd "C:\FOLDER_ABC\%verdir%\"
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.exe') DO %%G;

:FINISH
ECHO THE END
exit
```

Figured it out, but didn't have enough StackOverflow credits to answer my own question. My solution is listed below. Thanks everyone. You pointed me in the right direction.

```
cd "C:\FOLDER_ABC\%verdir%\"
FOR %%G in (*.exe) DO START %%G
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the START command:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.exe') DO START %%G;
```

There may be other better ways if achieving what you want, for example, if you know that the exe always has the same name as its directory, and that there will be only one such directory, you could do the following:

```
FOR /D %%i in (application-v*) DO START %i\%i.exe
```

**UPDATE**

From comments:

> My only issue, which I just realized, is that the application folder and application name are not always identical.

In that case, you could try something like:

```
for /d %%i in (application-v*) do for %%j in (%%i\*.exe) do start %%j
```

Comment: My only issue, which I just realized, is that the application folder and application name are not always identical. I want it to start any .exe within the app folder. C:\FOLDER_ABC\application-v1.3.4\Helloworld-v1.3.4.exe

Comment: I tried adding the app version to a parameter, just as I did with the folder, but I recieved the following error: 'C:\FOLDER_ABC\application-v1.3.4\application-v1.3.4.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b /a-d *.exe') DO start "" "%%~G"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but it is possible that the `;` is causing problems. You do not terminate commands with `;` in batch files.

There is no need for a temporary file. Your code can be greatly simplified with FOR:

```
pushd c:\folder_abc
for /d %%F in (application*) do cd "%%F"
for %%F in (*.exe) do "%%F"

:FINISH
ECHO THE END
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I figured out something similar that worked. I added it to the question above. Didn't have enough credits to answer my own question. Thanks! And the ";" was a typo. Sorry about that.